# IOS bluetooth, Apple wireless keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, bluetooth

I'm writing an IOS ZX Spectrum emulator, and so far all is going well. I've got the spectrum keys on the touch screen, and input feeding into the games, etc.

I'm wanting to add bluetooth keyboard support and am struggling to understand how to do this - I've got an Apple wireless keyboard, and this pairs to my iPad without problems (in the ios bluetooth setting panel). However, if I query the connectedAccessories property of a [EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager], it returns an empty array.

From reading around I think this means the Apple wireless keyboard is not mFi certified?

(I think if I was using a standard text input field e.g. UITextField, then this would work OK - problem is I'm not, and don't really want to - I don't want to use the IOS keyboard at all).

I'm not really interested in enumerating and adding / removing devices in my app (unless I really have to?), but I thought that it should be simple enough to get the key press/release states from the keyboard that's already paired in the iOS bluetooth settings panel.

To summarise, my question is:
Can I easily get the keyboard state for an iOS attached bluetooth keyboard (thats not necessarily MFI certified).

I don't want to use private API's or jailbreak (I'm baseline IOS 7 too if that helps).

(I've searched around but not found anything similar to this exact situation).

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer: The UIKeyInput protocol will give me key presses on the attached bluetooth keyboard (even though it's not MFi compliant).

However, it doesn't give me key state info (key down and key up events), and consequently isn't much help for my needs.

Just trying to work out if UIResponder can give me more (as UIKeyInput is a subclass of UIResponder).

Any help or insights appreciated.